# How to give gradient color to scrollbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the Scrollbar widget. Have tried the ScrollBarTheme but I cannot add gradient colors. Is there any way to build gradient coloured scrollbar in flutter?

Comment: add your code snippet for scrollbar

Comment: no, you cannot have gradients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might give you an idea of gradient scrollbar, [draggable_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_scrollbar):

```
DraggableScrollbar(
  controller: myScrollController,
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: myScrollController,
    itemCount: 1000,
    itemExtent: 100.0,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
          color: Colors.cyan[index % 9 * 100],
          child: Center(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  heightScrollThumb: 48.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  scrollThumbBuilder: (
    Color backgroundColor,
    Animation<double> thumbAnimation,
    Animation<double> labelAnimation,
    double height, {
    Text labelText,
  }) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: thumbAnimation,
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        width: 20.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Colors.blue,
              Colors.red,
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.